# How to Calculate Ticket Age wise Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
**Created Time**
2023-11-01 23:53:56
2023-11-01 22:32:02
2023-11-01 21:51:56
2023-10-18 12:19:46
2023-10-18 10:35:36
2023-10-17 10:27:21
2023-10-17 13:38:50
2023-10-17 11:44:44
2023-10-17 16:44:29
2023-10-17 11:54:54
2023-10-02 19:57:10
2023-10-02 17:43:55
2023-10-02 15:07:20
2023-10-02 11:35:39
2023-10-02 14:47:03
2023-08-03 17:08:57
2023-08-02 15:20:19
2023-08-02 14:50:45
2023-07-31 10:24:35
2023-07-29 14:48:46
2023-05-05 11:28:30
2023-05-05 16:37:14
2023-05-05 10:18:40
2023-05-05 10:38:03
2023-05-04 14:31:12
2022-10-29 16:19:22
2022-10-28 16:08:44
2022-10-27 11:25:03
2022-10-25 17:51:59
2022-10-23 11:23:57
2022-10-23 11:23:57
```

*As you can see,Above  Create Time Column and I want this below Format My Dataframe.*

```
Ticket Age   Created Time
1-15 Days   2023-11-01 23:53:56
1-15 Days   2023-11-01 22:32:02
1-15 Days   2023-11-01 21:51:56
1-15 Days   2023-10-18 12:19:46
1-15 Days   2023-10-18 10:35:36
16-30 Days  2023-10-17 10:27:21
16-30 Days  2023-10-17 13:38:50
16-30 Days  2023-10-17 11:44:44
16-30 Days  2023-10-17 16:44:29
16-30 Days  2023-10-17 11:54:54
1 - 3 Months    2023-10-02 19:57:10
1 - 3 Months    2023-10-02 17:43:55
1 - 3 Months    2023-10-02 15:07:20
1 - 3 Months    2023-10-02 11:35:39
1 - 3 Months    2023-10-02 14:47:03
3 - 6 Months    2023-08-03 17:08:57
3 - 6 Months    2023-08-02 15:20:19
3 - 6 Months    2023-08-02 14:50:45
3 - 6 Months    2023-07-31 10:24:35
3 - 6 Months    2023-07-29 14:48:46
6 Months - 1Yr  2023-05-05 11:28:30
6 Months - 1Yr  2023-05-05 16:37:14
6 Months - 1Yr  2023-05-05 10:18:40
6 Months - 1Yr  2023-05-05 10:38:03
6 Months - 1Yr  2023-05-04 14:31:12
More than 1Yr   2022-10-29 16:19:22
More than 1Yr   2022-10-28 16:08:44
More than 1Yr   2022-10-27 11:25:03
More than 1Yr   2022-10-25 17:51:59
More than 1Yr   2022-10-23 11:23:57
More than 1Yr   2022-10-23 11:23:57
```

I have need New Ticket Age Colums and Age wise 1-15 days,16-30 days,1-3 month, 6 month -1Yr, More then 1Yr

how to add age category wise age group

How can I do it?

Please advise.

I AM TRIYING FOLLOWING ERROR SHOW  HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE
[image]

Comment: How are you calculating the age? Current date-Created time?

Comment: What is the reference date? And was it necessary to have such a long example? Was there a reason why you couldn't make it shorter?

Comment: My reference date -Today....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for datetimes, subtract time now and get timedeltas in days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), so possible pass to [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for first new column:

```
df['Created Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created Time'])

days = df['Created Time'].rsub(pd.Timestamp('now')).dt.days.abs()

bins = [0,15,30,90,180,365,np.inf]
labels=["1-15 Days","16-30 Days","1-3 Months","3-6 Months","6 Months-1 Yr","More than 1Yr"]
df.insert(0,'Ticket Age', pd.cut(days, bins=bins, labels=labels))
```

---

```
print (df)
       Ticket Age        Created Time
0      16-30 Days 2023-11-01 23:53:56
1      16-30 Days 2023-11-01 22:32:02
2      16-30 Days 2023-11-01 21:51:56
3      1-3 Months 2023-10-18 12:19:46
4      1-3 Months 2023-10-18 10:35:36
5      1-3 Months 2023-10-17 10:27:21
6      1-3 Months 2023-10-17 13:38:50
7      1-3 Months 2023-10-17 11:44:44
8      1-3 Months 2023-10-17 16:44:29
9      1-3 Months 2023-10-17 11:54:54
10     1-3 Months 2023-10-02 19:57:10
11     1-3 Months 2023-10-02 17:43:55
12     1-3 Months 2023-10-02 15:07:20
13     1-3 Months 2023-10-02 11:35:39
14     1-3 Months 2023-10-02 14:47:03
15     3-6 Months 2023-08-03 17:08:57
16     3-6 Months 2023-08-02 15:20:19
17     3-6 Months 2023-08-02 14:50:45
18     3-6 Months 2023-07-31 10:24:35
19     3-6 Months 2023-07-29 14:48:46
20  6 Months-1 Yr 2023-05-05 11:28:30
21  6 Months-1 Yr 2023-05-05 16:37:14
22  6 Months-1 Yr 2023-05-05 10:18:40
23  6 Months-1 Yr 2023-05-05 10:38:03
24  6 Months-1 Yr 2023-05-04 14:31:12
25  More than 1Yr 2022-10-29 16:19:22
26  More than 1Yr 2022-10-28 16:08:44
27  More than 1Yr 2022-10-27 11:25:03
28  More than 1Yr 2022-10-25 17:51:59
29  More than 1Yr 2022-10-23 11:23:57
30  More than 1Yr 2022-10-23 11:23:57
```

Comment: Thank you very much and i really appreciate your help. Working fine .............

Comment: That's great :) Thanks for the explanation, Mr. Jezrael

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
def getDaysCategory(date_a_string, referenceDate) :
    date_a = datetime.strptime(date_a_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    days = abs((date_a - referenceDate).days)
    if (days <= 15) :
        return "1-15 Days"
    if (days >= 16 and days <= 30) :
        return "16-30 Days"
    if (days >= 31 and days <= 90) :
        return "1-3 Months"
    if (days >= 91 and days <= 180) :
        return "3-6 Months"
    if (days >= 181 and days <= 365) :
        return "6 Months-1 Yr"
    if (days > 365) :
        return "More than 1Yr"

today = datetime.today()
for date in dataframe :
    days = getDaysCategory(date, today)
```

`dataframe` is your dataframe object, just iterate over it and you will get your date category.

Comment: Thank you your Comment but not working

Comment: can you be more specific on what not working? is there any errors you facing, or output is unexpected?

Comment: ValueError: time data 'Created Time' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Comment: The above format working for me, are you sure you are passing each date properly, or can you share the code.

Comment: How to share code ....

Comment: you can add comment or add in your question by editing it.